# Excel: How to highlight value if greater than or less than previous column/row's last non-blank value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have a vehicle data spreadsheet with 3 columns to record the Odometer.

1. Odometer during repair service or fueling
2. Odometer at the **Beginning** of a trip
3. Odometer at the **End** of a trip

There are gaps between lines of data due to people not turning in paperwork or cancelled trips. So blank cells are inevitable.

I would like to use conditional formatting to highlight instances where the **Beginning** odometer is **LESS** than the last trip's **Ending** odometer. This will need to skip blank cells and find the last trip that had an ending odometer recorded.

I received help in google sheets to do this with the following formula, but this formula does not work in excel.

```
=(K9 > +sort(L$7:L8, not(isblank(L$7:L8)) * row(L$7:L8), false)) * not(isblank(K9)) * (+sort(L$7:L8, not(isblank(L$7:L8)) * row(L$7:L8), false) <> "Beginning")
```

Can someone help?

[Sample of Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RxRH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find the last non-blank in column L above the current row? Here's the formula you would put in row 2:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($L$1:$L1<>""),$L$1:$L1)
```

Note that the first `$L$1` is absolute for both column and row but the second `$L1` is relative for row so it'll update as you copy/paste down. The formula in row 3 (when you copy/paste/fill via table) will automatically be:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($L$1:$L2<>""),$L$1:$L2)
```

---

Now that you know how to do that, you can apply conditional formatting to the values in the range `K2:K1000` or wherever the end of your data is:

```
=AND(ROW()>2,NOT(ISBLANK(K2)),K2<LOOKUP(2,1/($L$1:$L1<>""),$L$1:$L1))
```

We had to add two exclusions:

1. Row > 2 because any number will be less than the literal text "Ending" which is what you get when you only consider the rows above 2.
2. The cell is not blank.

[image: Result]

Note: You don't need any formulas in in a helper column like shown in column N in the screenshot. I just left that in there so you could see how the formula in the conditional formatting is working.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without adding data in Column N? I'd like to just use formulas if possible, since I'll have 30+ vehicles to track.

Comment: You don't need any formulas in in a helper column like shown in column N in the screenshot. I just left that in there so you could see how the formula in the conditional formatting is working. I've added this note to the answer to avoid confusion for future users, too.